# What's the proper way to have mocha's `describe` inside of fast-check's `property`

Tags: javascript, typescript, mocha.js, property-based-testing

An alternative problem would be "How to check if mocha's `describe` has finished running all tests successfully".

I test an entity parameterized by several parameters (let's call it `a` and `b`). I have a test-suite for this entity encoded within [mocha](https://mochajs.org/)'s `describe:

```js
describe("entity", function () { 
  const entity = Entity(/*a =*/ 5, /*b =*/ 8);

  /* tests for entity */ 
}
```

The parameters are hard-coded. I want to property-check over them though (via [fast-check](https://github.com/dubzzz/fast-check)). So, I enclose the `Suite` into a type-check's property:

```
fc.assert(fc.property(fc.integer(), fc.integer(), (a, b) => 
  describe("entity", function () { 
    const entity = Entity(a, b);

    /* tests for entity */ 
  }
));
```

**The issue is**, fast-check doesn't register failed tests from the suite. Thus, it doesn't report parameters' value (`a` and `b`) on failures and doesn't try to minimize them.

It could be fixed, by manually checking if the `Suite` returned by `describe` has finished running all the tests successfully, and failing if not.

How should I approach the problem?